# RunUMAP in Seurat not working: module 'umap' has no attribute 'UMAP'

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, umap

I am trying to run `UMAP` in the following way:

```
RunUMAP(seurat_object, dims.use = 1:15, reduction.use = "pca", reduction.name = "umap", 
    reduction.key = "UMAP", n_neighbors = 30L, min_dist = 0.3, metric = "correlation")
```

Or just this:

```
RunUMAP(seurat_object, dims.use = 1:15, reduction.use = "pca")
```

It is giving me the error:

> Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
>     AttributeError: module 'umap' has no attribute 'UMAP'

I already installed `umap-learn` successfully in this way: `conda install -c conda-forge umap-learn` and checked that `Rstudio` is using the same `python` version as is provided by default in the terminal: `3.6.5`

Comment: You should post this on their github page as an issue, looks more like a software use or bug question rather than a bioinformatics question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved by installing the more recent version of the code from GitHub.

```
git clone https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap
cd umap
pip install --user -r requirements.txt
python setup.py install --user
```

As Peter said, this kind of question is best directed to the Issues page on their GitHub repository.